# Bulk processing XBRL into MySQL

Tags: linked-data, sql

I am working on a project involving processing a large volume of XBRL documents (> 1m separate files). I am totally new to XBRL and feeling quite lost at the moment, only downloaded Arelle 20 minutes ago).

I have data relating to those XBRL documents in a separate MySQL database and I would like to add XBRL data into MySQL to store it in one db.

What are the best methods to go about transferring data from the XBRL docs into MySQL?

Are there any bulk processing libraries available for it?

I've been looking for tutorials on those issues but couldn't find anything providing a basic introduction, just a lot of high level info.